# SX1509 Analog to Digital Converter?

Tags: adc, gpio, expander

I purchased this product:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11502

I've wired it up to 5 membrane pressure sensors which provide variable resistance depending on the pressure exerted. However I'm not sure if the GPIO expander I purchased above supports the analog signal coming from the pressure switches.

My issue is that the pressure switches are too sensitive and are giving false presses, and I was hoping I could use the variable resistance to calibrate how hard one must press to register, but I would need the analog signal to make this possible.

Here are the switches:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9375

Comment: What made you decide to not use a ADC?

Comment: Well I needed more outputs that what the Electric Imp breakout board provided, I used digital because AFAIK that is all my GPIO expander supports. I want to use an ADC (hopefully that already exists in the GPIO expander, as per my question).

Comment: @DylanVester  No such luck.  GPIO expander and A/D converter are different device classes.  The chip that you've got can read digital input (high => 1 or low => 0).  But it can not convert analog to digital (e.g. 1V => 77, 2.2V => 169, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such luck. GPIO expander and A/D converter are different device classes.  [The SX1509 chip that you've got](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/sx1509.pdf) can read digital input (high => 1 or low => 0).  But it can not convert analog to digital (e.g. 1V => 77, 2.2V => 169, etc).